# Determine Timezone based on offset and DST offset

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I was wondering if there was a way to build a java TimeZone object given the 2 **gmt-hour-offsets** as integers. For example, if I was given `(-5, -6)`, then I would like to be able to interpret that as **EST** time. Additionally, once I know what location it corresponds to, I want to be able to find out if a given date in that time zone is in DST or not. So ideally,

```
public static TimeZone getTimeZone(int offsetHrs, int dstOffsetHrs);
...
TimeZone tz = getTimeZone(-5, -6);
if(tz.isDST(currentDate)) {
    //Do stuff...
}
```

And then if offsetHours and dstOffsetHrs are the same, then we ignore dst.... Don't ask why, it's a requirement that I either need to confirm can be done, or else I'll need to look at some major changes elsewhere.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've looked at TimeZone (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) right?  In the first sentence of the javadoc it states "TimeZone represents a time zone offset, and also figures out daylight savings."  Isn't that what you're looking for?  Mostly?

Comment: @hooknc Not exactly, b/c the timezone instances can only be constructed with known time zone names/identifiers. It does not have a way to build it based on arbitrary offsets, and then compare it to existing ones... Although I could potentially do that I guess..

Comment: The TimeZone class has a getAvailableIDs(int rawOffset) method, which you can use to return a list of TimeZone IDs with a given offset. That doesn't take into account the dstOffset though, so you'd need to do something with that list to narrow it down to those which actually observe DST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there can be multiple time zones with the same offsets, but which transition on different dates. Of course if you're happy to accept that potential ambiguity, it shouldn't be impossible...

For example, using a Joda [`DateTimeZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) you'd probably want to start off with some fixed date (e.g. January 1st 2010) and look through the next few transitions of each time zone - if the time zone *has* transitions - to work out what its standard/daylight offsets are. You can then use `isStandardOffset` to determine whether a particular instant is in DST or standard time.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I figured (and feared). Thanks for the confirmation. I'll have to look into some way of using the current default time and fiddle as necessary.